How to read a complextype using ua-.netstandard
I'm using UA-.NETStandard to develop an OPC UA client/server with .NET, but I’m facing some challenges. Here’s my code:
var session = Session.Create(
    config,
    new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, selectedEndpoint, EndpointConfiguration.Create(config)),
    false, "", 60000, null, null
).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

InitializeComplexTypeSystem(session);

var result = session.ReadValue("ns=3;s=\"H35dispenser\".\"ID\"");

public static ComplexTypeSystem InitializeComplexTypeSystem(Session session)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Initializing ComplexTypeSystem");
    ComplexTypeSystem complexTypeSystem = new ComplexTypeSystem(session);
    complexTypeSystem.Load().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Initialized ComplexTypeSystem");
    return complexTypeSystem;
}

The code successfully reads the specified node on the PLC, but the node uses a custom UDT. While I could manually parse the response to match the data structure, I’m hoping there’s a better way to handle custom UDTs. I’ve checked the examples on the UA-.NETStandard GitHub but haven’t found a solution. Any guidance? The node itself looks as follows:


You might be interested in this: 'EncodeableFactory.GlobalFactory.AddEncodeableType(typeof(Opc.Complex.Types.YourComplexType))'
You will have to define (auto generate if possible) your complex type in your c# code beforehand.
This answer can point you in the right direction. It uses the custom complex 'Vector' type.

Requirement to know data types before compilation is too restrictive in my opinion. Our C++ SDK discovers custom data types at runtime: https://onewayautomation.com/opcua-sdk
